# Cannot erase internal SSD You cannot manually format an existing APFS Container disk

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, disk-utility, ssd

I'm trying to erase the internal SSD on my Mac as when the computer boots up it goes haywire and stops responding. I've got a Mac installer on USB, but I cannot erase the drive.

When I try to erase the disk it says **You cannot manually format an existing APFS Container disk**

I've tried deleting the APFS Containers and Volumes as much as I can

Please look at the screenshot of terminal for what it says. I'd be really grateful if anyone can help.

[image]

Comment: From the screenshot it seems that you booted from the internal disk, so you can't change it. Try to install macOS on an internal drive first, and boot from there; or boot into Recovery.

Comment: Could you try to copy/paste what you see in Terminal instead of adding a screenshot? Some parts are not really readable

Answer (score 1):

Type: `diskutil apfs list` to find all the containers on your disk.

Once you have them, use `diskutil apfs deleteVolume /dev/disk[NUM]s[NUM]` to delete volume.

then, `diskutil apfs deleteContainer /dev/disk[NUM]`.

If everything is working properly, your disk's file system should now be back to JHFS.